# MapBox GL pure CSS markers with numbers

Tags: javascript, css, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Based on the [mapbox example](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/custom-markers-gl-js/) of how to add markers

I would like to make a teardrop marker that is pure css, not an image. I would also like to number the markers from a for loop index. Is it possible to create tear drop markers? Can anyone help with this? I can't seem to find a good example from mapbox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.52.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.52.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
        .marker {
            background-image: url('mapbox-icon.png');
            background-size: cover;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .mapboxgl-popup {
            max-width: 200px;
        }
        .mapboxgl-popup-content {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>

<script>

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZXhhbXBsZXMiLCJhIjoiY2lqbmpqazdlMDBsdnRva284cWd3bm11byJ9.V6Hg2oYJwMAxeoR9GEzkAA';

var geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
         "type": "Feature",
         "geometry": {
             "type": "Point",
             "coordinates": [-77.032, 38.913]
         },
         "properties": {
             "title": "Mapbox",
             "description": "Washington, D.C."
         }
     },
     {
         "type": "Feature",
         "geometry": {
         "type": "Point",
         "coordinates": [-122.414, 37.776]
        },
         "properties": {
             "title": "Mapbox",
             "description": "San Francisco, California"
         }
     }]
};

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
    center: [-96, 37.8],
    zoom: 3
});

// add markers to map
geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {

    // create a HTML element for each feature
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';

    // make a marker for each feature and add it to the map
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
        .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
        .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({offset: 25}) // add popups
            .setHTML('<h3>' + marker.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description + '</p>'))
        .addTo(map);
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may set whatever you want HTML as a marker and style it the way you want:

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoid2hpdGVwYWdlcyIsImEiOiJjamp0MW1wYjQwMHZzM2twZTI2b21vdjA3In0.VvrdwQHoAEoD3RfFxe3s2Q';

var geojson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-77.032, 38.913]
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Mapbox",
        "description": "Washington, D.C."
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-122.414, 37.776]
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Mapbox",
        "description": "San Francisco, California"
      }
    }
  ]
};

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
  center: [-96, 37.8],
  zoom: 3
});

// add markers to map
geojson.features.forEach(function(marker, i) {

  // create a HTML element for each feature
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = 'marker';
  el.innerHTML = '<span><b>' + (i + 1) + '</b></span>'

  // make a marker for each feature and add it to the map
  new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
    .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({
        offset: 25
      }) // add popups
      .setHTML('<h3>' + marker.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description + '</p>'))
    .addTo(map);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.marker {width:0; height:0;}

.marker  span {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  color:#fff;
  background: #693;
  border:solid 2px;
  border-radius: 0 70% 70%;
  box-shadow:0 0 2px #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-origin:0 0;
  transform: rotateZ(-135deg);
}

.marker b {transform: rotateZ(135deg)}

.mapboxgl-popup {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-content {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.52.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.52.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: U sir are a saint!